# WCF Service Update gives Error

Tags: wcf

I have WCF service running on netTcpBinding, everything fine I have some more functions and classes to the Service when I am updating my Service Reference at client project(WPF project) it gives an error :-

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   net.tcp://localhost:6001/Admin/mex If
>   this is a Windows (R) Communication
>   Foundation service to which you have
>   access, please check that you have
>   enabled metadata publishing at the
>   specified address.  For help enabling
>   metadata publishing, please refer to
>   the MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata
>   Exchange Error    URI:
>   net.tcp://localhost:6001/Admin/mex
>   Metadata contains a reference that
>   cannot be resolved:
>   'net.tcp://localhost:6001/Admin/mex'. 
>   Could not connect to
>   net.tcp://localhost:6001/Admin/mex.
>   The connection attempt lasted for a
>   time span of 00:00:00.9039880. TCP
>   error code 10061: No connection could
>   be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it 127.0.0.1:6001.
>   No connection could be made because
>   the target machine actively refused it
>   127.0.0.1:6001

I have valid endpoint added for Mex Endpoint in my config and even Reader Quota has been set to maximum. Any solution for this ?

Comment: Show your service configuration. You can also try to delete reference and create a new one.

Comment: I have tried deleting the Service and creating a new one but still it gives error!!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha!! Finally got an answer. Though nobody has posted any answer, i am answering my question because some one like me, if searching for this problem he gets proper solution to it.

This is a known issue with WCF.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/17592561-c470-452a-a52c-2a5a2839582c/

Secondly we can fix it by changing configs

http://geekswithblogs.net/claraoscura/archive/2007/08/20/114806.aspx